# I have created two collections but when I am trying to insert data in one collection it is not inserting in one collection

Tags: mean-stack

I am trying two insert data into two collections using Mean.

I created two collections but I am unable to insert data into that through api.

This is user.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true},
    email: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true },
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var user = this;
     bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) return next(err); // Exit if error is found
        user.password = hash; // Assign the hash to the user's password so it is saved in database encrypted
        next(); // Exit Bcrypt function
    });
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password); // Returns true if password matches, false if doesn't
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users',UserSchema);


var UserSchema1 = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true},
    email: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User1',UserSchema1);
```

and my controller looks like this

```
angular.module('user1Controllers',[])

.controller('reg1Ctrl',function($http, $location){

    var app = this;

    this.regUsers = function(reg1Data){

        console.log(this.reg1Data);
        $http.post('/api/user1',this.reg1Data);
    };
});
```